# Using %~dp0 for MSIExec Logfile Output

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I'm trying to output my logfiles to a subfolder relative to my install script, and MSIExec doesn't seem to like it when used with the "/l*v" command. I've tried variations of %~dp0Logs (with and without quotes, etc.). If I manually enter the full path like: /l*v c:\scripts\logs\%computername%.txt" it works fine, but the script is always going to be in different locations (USB, network, etc.).

I see references online to using the %temp% system variable which I guess works, but not the parent lookup folder variable of %dp0. And I'm using the same variable elsewhere in my script for other things, like running the MSI and file copy commands (copy "%~dp0Files\Images\%LogonBackgroundWinXP%"...). I've even tried setting a variable like: Set LogFolder=%dp0\logs, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Am I missing something or am I just going to have to find another folder lookup method just for my log files?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I guess all I needed was a few hours away from this and lunch! Works perfectly fine, not sure what I was doing wrong before. I was going to do a copy command afterwards, but now I don't have to.